# Can't convert HTML to plain text: ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have below HTML text retrieved from sql server.

```
"<span style="color: rgb(36, 39, 41); font-family: Arial, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">So, first method looks nice and it's easy but is there is any simpler way to write the second function? Both are working well and giving a correct output.</span>"
```

I want to convert html to plain text and set it on a label in asp.net.

**To do this:**

1. I have retrieved data from sql server in Dataset.
2. Set above retrieved to label

   ```
        <h3 id="lblqNotes" runat="server" class="text-questiondata" style="color:#1E90FF">
      </h3>
   ```

**In code behind:**

```
  lblqNotes.InnerText = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(values[2]);
```

But output on label is still html code, not plain text.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean HtmlEncode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: HtmlEncode is not for converting into PlainText. is it?

Comment: Why don't you read what it does, friend?

Comment: "HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings &lt; and &gt;, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly."

Comment: Understood. But that's not what I am looking for. What I need to do is to convert it into plain text. For ex: HTML <b>hello</b>. output should be hello in bold

Comment: you mean Raw? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx or decode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: is HtmlHelper class only for mvc?

Comment: It's a library like any other that you can reference. It would be overkill in this case, but you didn't say you're not using mvc.

Comment: Yeah. its not MVC. How do I make it work?

Comment: How about you change lblqNotes.InnerText to lblqNotes.InnerHtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `XmlDocument`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        var html = @"<span style=""color: rgb(36, 39, 41); font - family: Arial, &quot; Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, sans - serif; font - size: 15px; background - color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "">So, first method looks nice and it's easy but is there is any simpler way to write the second function? Both are working well and giving a correct output.</span>";
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(html);

        var text = xmlDocument.InnerText;
        // So, first method looks nice and it's easy but is there is any simpler way to write the second function? Both are working well and giving a correct output.
    }
```

Comment: Amazing. Simplest  thing to do. Just a question. How do I use "@" with a variable which has html code in LoadXmL method like xmlDocument.LoadXml(@<variablename>)??

Comment: @ is just a verbatim string, I've updated the question to pull out that variable

Comment: that works, but in my case I am pulling data from db and storing data into a variable. So how do I put @ to that varibale? I tried this string var= @values[2]; but it throws error. here values[2] have html code.

Comment: Just removed the @ and will work fine for your problem

Comment: But in case where I have multiple tags in a variable, like this: <span style="color: rgb(36, 39, 41); font-family: Arial, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">I have a given String that represents the age in format:</span><br style="color: rgb(36, 39, 41);">, It throws error saying there are multiple root elements. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Just wrap the whole bock in a <root> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to strip out the Html by using a regex : `output = Regex.Replace(source, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);`

Comment: This makes me think of this beauty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It is just for stripping html characters. What I need to do is to convert it into plain text. For ex: HTML <b>hello</b>. output  should be hello in bold.

Comment: What you need is an Html parser check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c